# how to set up a dotnet5.0 solution to compile / build on macbook pro with m1 chip?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core, apple-m1

I just changed my dev machine from a windows box to a macbook pro (m1 chip).  I need to be able to build / compile / debug a dotnet 5.0 project.

I'm assuming I can download multiple versions of the SDK and runtimes on my mac ... like the net6.0 for arm64 bit and net5.0 x64. (doesn't seem to be arm64 for .net 5.0 per the docs)

I've installed both SDKS using these two dotnet installers you see below:

```
me@MmMacBook-Pro ~ % ls -lah ~/Downloads 
total 1469464
drwx------+ 10 me  staff   320B 23 Jan 14:01 .
drwxr-x---+ 27 me  staff   864B 23 Jan 14:00 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   6.0K 23 Jan 13:41 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff     0B 21 Jan 15:07 .localized
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   104M 21 Jan 23:24 VSCode-darwin-arm64.zip
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   167M 22 Jan 14:38 azuredatastudio-macos-1.34.0.zip
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   261M 23 Jan 13:17 dotnet-sdk-5.0.404-osx-x64.pkg
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   159M 23 Jan 13:38 dotnet-sdk-6.0.101-osx-arm64.pkg
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    26M 21 Jan 23:53 git-2.33.0-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg
```

I didn't get any errors during either install.  But at this point, when I check the list of dotnet sdks, I only see the 6.0 version:

```
me@Mm-MacBook-Pro ~ % dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.101
 Commit:    ef49f6213a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  12.1
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.12-arm64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.1
  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

me@Mm-MacBook-Pro ~ % dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

When I manually check the contents of /usr/local/share/dotnet I see that I have an x64 folder:

```
me@Mm-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -lah /usr/local/share/dotnet/               
total 456
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel   384B 23 Jan 14:10 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96B 22 Jan 15:08 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1.1K 17 Nov 13:14 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    77K 17 Nov 13:14 ThirdPartyNotices.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   142K 23 Nov 14:58 dotnet
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96B 17 Nov 13:30 host
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192B 23 Jan 14:10 packs
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96B 20 Nov 01:14 sdk
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96B 20 Nov 01:15 sdk-manifests
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128B 22 Jan 15:08 shared
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96B 20 Nov 01:15 templates
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel   320B 23 Jan 13:58 x64
```

Can someone point me in the right direction / tell me where I'm going wrong?

Just to be sure that the 6.0 install is working, I spun up a new project like this:

```
 dotnet new webapp
```

and I was able to compile.

Thanks.

Édit 1

Per the comments just going to upgrade the project to 6.0.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the design doc for supporting both x64 and arm64 .NET 6 on M1 for some ideas: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2021/architecture-targeting.md

Comment: .NET 5 is not supported on M1 and reaches end of life this May, so migrating to .NET 6 is the only option.